# Mapreduce in Hadoop gives GC overhead limit exceeded when using files over 200MB

Tags: java, hadoop, garbage-collection

I am running a Mapreduce code on Hadoop Multi-Node Cluster (2.4.1). I get the error GC overhead limit exceeded when I try to run with 2 input files of sizes 200MB and 200MB. This runs perfectly and got correct output when i use very small files.

My aim is to compare every flow record in 1st file to every flow-record in 2nd file and compute distance, then take 10 maximum values and output to reducer based on these 10 max. values.
Example flow record in both files - 194.144.0.27|192.168.1.5|0.0.0.0|0|0|2|104|1410985350|1410985350|51915|51413|6|6

Few Snapshots: http://goo.gl/5tUhJJ  and http://goo.gl/lh1Qvm

Here is Mapper Class:

**Mapper Class:**

```
public class mapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> 
{

 private final static IntWritable five = new IntWritable(5);

 private Text counter1;

 ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
 String str;
 BufferedReader br,in;
 int ddos_line = 0; 
 int normal_line = 0,total_testing_records=4000;
 int K = 10;

  @Override
  protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
  { 
     //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("normal"));

      Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();          
      URI[] cachefiles = context.getCacheFiles();

      FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());          
      FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path(cachefiles[0].toString()));            
      BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(status[0].getPath()))); 


      while((str = in.readLine()) != null)
      {
          lines.add(str);
      }
      in.close();
      //System.out.println("na netti");
  }

@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{

    String line1 = value.toString();
    ddos_line++;
    normal_line = 0;

    double[] count = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
    int[] lineIndex = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    String[] parts = line1.split("\\|");
    String[] linesArray = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);  

    boolean bool = true;
    int t1=0;
    double sum=0;
    while (bool) 
    {
        for(int i=0; i<K;i++)
        {
                if(bool==false) break;
                sum = 0;
                String[] parts2 = linesArray[normal_line].split("\\|");

                for(int x=0;x<13;x++)
                    {
                            if(parts[x].equals(parts2[x]))
                            {
                                t1 = 1;
                            }
                            else t1 = 0;

                            sum += t1;
                    }

                    sum = Math.sqrt(sum);

                    if(count[K-1] <= sum)
                    {
                        count[K-1] = sum;
                        lineIndex[K-1]=normal_line;
                    } 



                    for(int k=0;k<K;k++)
                    {
                        for(int j=0;j<K-1;j++)
                        {   
                            if(count[j] < count[j+1]) 
                            {
                                double temp2 = count[j+1];
                                count[j+1] = count[j];
                                count[j] = temp2;

                                int temp3 = lineIndex[j+1];
                                lineIndex[j+1] = lineIndex[j];
                                lineIndex[j] = temp3;
                            }
                         }
                     }

                //System.out.println(ddos_line + "   " + normal_line);
                if (normal_line + 1 < linesArray.length)
                {
                    normal_line++;
                    continue;
                } 

                else bool = false;
            }


    } // while end

    char[] t = {'d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d'};
    for(int i=0;i<K;i++)
    {
        if(lineIndex[i] <= total_testing_records/2 ) t[i] = 'n'; 
    }

    int counter_normal=0, counter_ddos=0;
    for(int i=0;i<K;i++)
    {
        if(t[i]=='n')
            counter_normal++;
        else
            counter_ddos++;
        //System.out.println("t[i]: "+t[i]+", counter: "+counter_ddos);

    }

    if(counter_normal<=K/2)
    {
        counter1 = new Text(ddos_line + " : d : "+ counter_ddos);
    }
    else
    {
        counter1 = new Text(ddos_line + " : n : "+ (counter_normal));
    }



    context.write(counter1, five);

    //System.out.println("mapper finished");    
}
  public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
  {
      setup(context);
      while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
            map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
      }
      cleanup(context);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply increase the memory of your tasks then:

Set

```
mapred.child.java.opts
```

in your job configuration to

```
-Xmx1024m
```

or more, whatever you need to read this file and process it.

Comment: What is your cluster configuration? @kishorer747

Comment: sorry it was for Kishorer747 not seen you answer

Comment: My Cluster is Hadoop 2.4.1 5-node cluster with dual-core processors and 8 GB ram for each pc. I tried setting higher than 2 gigs using -Xmx* , but got the same error.

Comment: @kishorer747 then you have a memory leak somewhere